# HTML5 - offline mode, localStorage and security are on a boat

Tags: javascript, html, cryptography, local-storage, offline

My clients wants to be able to work **online** and **offline** to manipulate data, typically create or retrieve products.

While online, he wants to uses web services and the server database, but when offline (network breakup or whatever), he wants the data to be **persisted and encrypted in the localStorage**.

I'm going for a javascript crypto lib, getting the password from the login page and using password derived key for the encryption passphrase. The key would be stored in a simple javascript var (the page is dynamic, so no page change).

What are your inputs on the matter and what solution would you preconise ? Any good javascript crypto lib ?

Comment: dnt u think, the key is in javascript var is insecure?

Comment: I totally think so, that's why I'm asking for a better solution (not The solution, as client-side encryption will still be a long way from secure).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solutions is as you say ,to derive the key from the clients password. That way you never have to store it directly. This is the technique used by last pass, a password manager. The function most people use for this is PBKDF2. Storing the key in a simple var is not really insecure in that if someone can read that var, they could read the data your client is working on. Just make sure you clear the data when the client logs out

Thankfully, this [library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) already does almost all of these things very well and was written by real honest to god cryptographers and not some web 2.0 guy who read  Bruce Schneier's book and thought they knew all there is to know about crypto.

Comment: PBKDF2 is "pseudorandom", I guess it means each derivation from the password outputs a new key. That's fine if the data lifetime were bound to the browser session, but what happens if I need it to persist in localStorage ? New browser session would imply new key, thus I wouldn't be able to decrypt the content, right ?

Comment: pseudorandom means random looking but deterministic effectively. Provided you give it the same salt and password, you will get the same key. So store the salt with the data. Really though, the linked javascrypt crypto library does what you want

Comment: Nice answer. I did not know about **SJCL** until this post.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cryptographic_Storage_Cheat_Sheet has a good guide for storing data at rest.